# using c code in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Objective C is meant to support C. I have some code in C language and I want to use it in objective C how is that possible? I know it is possible but I am not sure how.

**Edit**
I want to use following code in objective C. How can I do it?

```
string FileMeasure="Hello FILE!"
int TempNumOne=FileMeasure.size();
char Filename[100];
for (int a=0;a<=TempNumOne;a++)
{
    Filename[a]=FileMeasure[a];
}
```

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: C code **is** Objective-C code.

Comment: Note that the code in your question is not valid C. It looks like you’re mixing C with C++.

Comment: Yes. That’s called Objective-C++; any C++ code is also valid Objective-C++ code.

Comment: but when I am trying to use it I am getting error

Comment: See my answer. What error do you get?

Comment: @Bavarious not true. Only a subset of C++ compiles as Objective-C++. For example, vtables are not supported.

Comment: @Shaggy Could you point me to some reference or sample code?

Comment: @Bavarious http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B

Comment: @Shaggy That doesn’t mean that there exists C++ code that is not valid Objective-C++ code, much less that vtables aren’t supported.

Comment: @Bavarious I think you need to re-read it again. It certainly does.

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C is just a kind of layer over C...

If you have C libraries, C code, C functions, or whatever, you'll be able to use them from Objective-C...

Just think about Objective-C as a wrapper for object-oriented C code...

Maybe you'll have to add details, if you want a more specific answer...

Answer (score 1):

> Objective C is meant to support C.

Not sure what this means. Objective-C is a superset of C.

> I have some code in C language and I want to use it in objective C

Just use it. Generally there's no magic required.

Answer (score 0):

As language, you can consider Objective-C a "super set" of C, so that pure C code works fine when compiled in a Obj-C project; but this is about the language itself, the standard library (it is available in Obj-C as well), and any library with "C linkage". If it makes sense and if it will work or not depends on what exactly the C code does. E.g. if it uses a system-specific library, there could be a porting issue.